# iPhone memory managment leak in mapkit 32 bytes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks

My problem is same as
[Leaking NSAutoreleasePool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156517/leaking-nsautoreleasepool)
here I am not allocating any autoreleasepool there is only one autoreleasepool and that is of main.No multithreading. I am running my app on simulator 4.1.here in this discussion I am not finding the exact solution so if any one can share his/her idea on this will be appreciated,

Comment: Past the code where you think it is leaking.

Comment: hi actually the instrument is  not pointing to any code.but i think it is leaking in viewWillAppear method where i am allocating the mapview i think MapKit TileCachePrivate::runCacheThread() is causing problem as par the leak instrument.hope you understand if not please let me know since i am new to iphone

Comment: Did you try to analyze it. Hit shift+cmd+B. It should get you more info about potential leaks.

Comment: Pls, use edit question function to add the console log and mark it as a code. In the stackctrace you are interested in a line where you see one of you class names, not the framework clases.

Comment: hello sir in stacktrace i am not getting my classname only it shows leak in framework clases.

Comment: Then the only other way to track the leak is to insert brakes in the code and trying to see manually when the leak will show up.

Comment: In the past I've occasionally found that some Apple APIs leak memory in the simulator but not on the device.  You might want to try running profiling on an actual device before you spend too much time on this.

Comment: ok i ran the app on actual device but still it's giving the same leak ,but my app does not crash due to that.I think there is something with apple api.